# How do you quick travel in Lego Lord of the Rings?

Tags: lego-lord-of-the-rings

I've just picked up LEGO Lord of the Rings and even though I've only completed the first four levels I'm finding tedious to have to walk, run or (rarely) ride back to the previous locations to complete side quests and visit the blacksmith at Bree to forge Mithril items.

Is there any way I can "quick travel" or teleport between locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the map statues to quick travel between locations.

Go to the map and find the map stone you want to fast travel to, then press A. This will transport you to that location.

You can only quick travel to map statues that you have previously activated.

Answer (score 1):

On the PC version, if you hit `<escape>` you can select "go to map" so you can teleport anywhere without having to find a mapstone.